# Scrolling through UICollectionView keeps on updating values

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView in my project, where I am adding the quantity of items added in each cell, and displaying the total in a UIBarButtonItem. However, when I scroll through the view the number keeps on changing. I understand that this issue is related to the fact that collection and table views reuse cells, and I have done much research about it, but I can't solve the problem. Overriding "prepareForUse()" didn't help either. I'm still a beginner so excuse me if I'm naive. Thanks in advance.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = trayCell.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "trayCell", for: indexPath) as! TrayItemCollectionViewCell

        //initializing labels

        if let quantity = arrayOfOrders[indexPath.row]["quantity"] as? Int{
            totalQuantity += quantity
            trayButton.title = "\(totalQuantity)"
        }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You are trying to show the total number of items in the whole collection view in a bar button title?

Comment: @Bader Yusuf Serhan There is a difference keeps on changing or repeating?

Comment: Please show more code for the collection view

Comment: @jegadeesh my application is a restaurant menu, you choose a set of items as well as quantity for each item, so I am trying to show total quantity. it is working fine but when i scroll down or back up, the value keeps on changing as the cells reload

Comment: @TusharSharma the number keeps on increasing since it is adding each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your code for `trayButton` title update outside `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method.

`collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` will be called every time cell is presented. Ideal flow for you would be updating that title right after you get your `arrayOfOrders` (in `viewDidLoad:` potentially) with following code:

```
/// Get array of quantities
let quantityArray = arrayOfOrders.flatMap { $0["quantity"] as? Int }

/// Get sum
let totalQuantity = quantityArray.reduce(0, +)

/// Update button title
trayButton.title = "\(totalQuantity)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (index, element) in arrayOfOrders.enumerate()
{
    if let quantity = element["quantity"] as? Int{
            totalQuantity += quantity  
        }
    trayButton.title = "\(totalQuantity)"
}
```

Do like this. (I didn't check this, So do some adjustments if needed.)

Comment: my problem is actually with the scrolling of the collection view :(

Answer (score -1):

Using for Loop Add all Value of quantity from arrayOfOrders each time you reload the tableView. this is only way.